# How to update data programmatically in DataGridView using c#

Tags: c#, string, datagridview

In my dataGridView cells values are 0's and 1's. I have to set 0 to A and 1 to P by using following code for this operation.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    int d = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
    if (d == 0)
        row.Cells[0].Value = "A";
    else
        row.Cells[0].Value = "P";
}
```

but it gives error, error is like

System.Exception: A is not a valid value for Int32. -> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct
format.
    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatinfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.Parselnt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatinfo info) ... continue

**If I set the numerical value in above program it update successfully but if I set string value like "A" or "P" it gives above error.**

Please give me the solutions.

Comment: What is the string value? What is the error?? After setting it to a string you obviously can't convert it to a proper index..

Comment: `row.Cells[i].Value = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString() == "0" ? "A" : "P"`, aybe..?

Comment: Is your DataGridView bound to anything?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know about the bound

Comment: Does it have a DataSource?

Comment: when just draw the datagridview. Open popup on tight corner I am selecting from there sir. And shows the whole data exact as database this data contains 0 and 1 and I have to update as above need

Comment: Can you please show the code where the DataGridView gets populated?

Comment: There is no any code sir just set in the properties

Comment: I am not sure what the “mystery” is here. Your last comment… _”If I set the numerical value in above program it update successfully but if I set string value like "A" or "P" it gives above error.”_ … The error seems straight forward… “A is not a valid value for Int32” … When the `string` value passed to the `Convert.ToInt32(stringValue)` is NOT a number, which “A” is not a number, you will get this `FormatException.` So, I am not sure what is not clear.

Comment: The posted code looks odd… If the grid initially starts where some _”cells values are 0's and 1's”_ … then, whenever you run the posted code… it would appear you would ONLY be able to run the code successfully ONCE. The first time it is run, the code “changes” the cell(s) value such that if the cell contained a zero (0) then replace the zero with an “A.” If the cell originally contains a One (1) then replace it with “P.”

Comment: This appears fairly straight forward, however if you attempt to run the code a second time, then, it is going give you the error you are seeing on the line `int d = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);` for obvious reasons. Can you clarify “why” it is necessary to convert these Boolean values to strings? Is the user able to edit/change these values? How are the values stored?

Comment: This is attendance by biometric device I store this data in 0 and 1 that's why I have to convert it in 0 for A mean "Absent" and 1 for P mean "Present". Color set as per need but A and P can't be set

Comment: And if I set the A and P in Name column it sets successfully but can't set in numerical column like attendance column

Comment: I am lost as to why it is confusing that the line of code… `int d = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);` is FAILING if `row.Cells[0].Value` is an “A” or a “P.” It is NOT clear “how” the data is getting into the grid. If the data comes from a database and the “original” data in column zero (0) consist only of zero’s (0) and ones (1), then I can only assume that column zero (0) is of type `bool` or `int.` It IS possible for the type to be `string` also. However, this is speculation. You should clarify this.

Comment: If the column “type” is `bool` or `int`, then you would get the grids dreaded `DataError` if you attempted to put an “A” or “P” into a cell in that column. However, this does not appear to be the error you are getting. The posted error is clearly coming from the line… `Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);` In addition it is clear from the error that the value in `row.Cells[0].Value` IS AN “A.” which means the posted code has already run at least once.

Comment: As I previously stated, the posted code can ONLY BE RUN ONCE. If the posted code runs successfully once and replaces the “0s” with “As” and “1s” to “Ps”… then the second time the code is run (which appears to be the case) … it will FAIL on the line… `int d = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);` for obvious reasons which I hope you can see.

Comment: If the data is stored as zeros (0s) and ones (1s)… then you should to make this conversion after reading in the data and BEFORE you attach the data to the grid. In addition, if you want to “Save” the grid data to file or database, then the code is going to have to convert the values back. If you are setting up the grids data source in the “designer”, then, this is going to make the conversion more difficult and it would be easier to get the data first (in the code) then make the conversion THEN set the data source to the grid.

Comment: Lastly, It would be helpful to know “where” the posted code getting called? Basically, there is too much missing info to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Even in the first time when loop start gives above error in line "row.Cells[0].Value = "A";" there is no error in line "int d = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);" and also it recovers cell value successfully like 0 or 1.

Comment: database table gates by using TableAdapter code is"this.attendanceTableAdapter.Fill(this.dBDataSet.Attendance);"

Comment: column type is integer in database and I don't know what is type in dataGridView

Comment: No any type of Add, Update operation perform on it. It just showing the Table.

Comment: Lastly If I update the cell value of Name column individually by using code "dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "stringValue";" is succeed. And if I update the cell value of other column it contains values of 0's and 1's by using code "dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = "A";" it gives same error

Comment: IF column[0] is of “type” `int` which I assume it IS from your comment… _”column type is integer in database”_ … then the line of code… `row.Cells[0].Value = "A";` is going to FAIL for obvious reasons, namely… “A” is NOT a valid `int`. It appears you want to put “A’s” and “P’s” into an `int` column… which will NOT work. As previously stated, you are going to have to change the columns “type” to a `string` type to allow alpha characters like “A.” You can do this when you read from the database, or, create a method to “convert” the column from `int` to `string.`

Comment: Sir, in my database column type is integer but when I am getting the data in datagridview I don't know how to set automatically column type of datagridview. If you know how to change column type of datagridview programmatically please comment me.

Comment: I have recently changed the column type in string by using code "dataGridView1.Columns[1].ValueType = typeof(string);". I have also confirm to print the column type by using code "Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Columns[1].ValueType);" before and after execution of the code "dataGridView1.Columns[1].ValueType = typeof(string);". Before the code execution print "System.Int32" and after the code execution print "System.String". Mean type changed to string but it not set the "A" or "P" upto now.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, to avoid this unnecessary back and forth inquisition, it would behoove you to include all the pertinent information in your question. Example in this case, the code that adds the data to the grid would benefit YOU by removing any question as to “how” the code is doing this. If others wanted to help you, then they are going to have to “guess” how this is done. If others (who you are asking help from) have to do a bunch of guessing and code writing to reproduce YOUR question… then most are going to move on.

I highly recommend that you take a look at the SO section on… [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ...I can not stress how helpful this “process” can be for YOU. Often times, the process of creating the “reproducible” example that you want to post here “reveals” the problem you are having. Posting a “complete reproducible example` will help you since the other people helping you don’t have to guess or write a bunch of code. Without question, you will get more and better answers to your questions if you do this simple thing.

As seen from the back and forth questions and answers, it seems to me that we are getting nowhere. Given your last comment, I am guessing you may be looking at this from the point of view of the `DataGridView` your comment…

> *”I have recently changed the column type in string by using code "dataGridView1.Columns[ 1 ].ValueType = typeof(string);". I have also
>   confirm to print the column type by using code
>   "Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Columns[1 ].ValueType);" before and
>   after execution of the code "dataGridView1.Columns[1 ].ValueType =
>   typeof(string);"”*

Changing the “ValueType” IN THE GRID is fine, however, you need to keep in mind, that the “underlying” data source won’t necessarily respect/conform to the “GRIDS” value type. In fact in most cases, as this one… it WON’T. You can test this by doing the following steps:

1) Load the data into the grid such that the column we want to change is a “numeric” column.

2) Change that column to a string value type as your posted code does in your comment.

3) Type an “A” into the column you just changed to a `string type` then press the “Enter” key…

I am betting you will get a `DataError` exception.

It is true, your code changes the column type to a `string` IN THE GRID, but the underlying data source is still an `int`. Hence the `DataError`. The `DataGridView` simply displays the data that is in the data source. You can change the column types, format and order in the GRID, however, the underlying data source “usually” will NOT change. This is why, in your case, you need to “change” the column type in the data source, not the grid.

There are numerous ways to achieve this, however, IMHO I am betting the “easiest” way to do this would be to change the column type and possibly the values also “when you get the data from the data base.” I am aware this may not be an option at times and you are forced to make the changes you are asking for. But if you can do this directly from the data base, I recommend it.

Therefore, lets break down what I can gather you are asking. For starters, I assume you are getting the data from a data base and the data is returned in a `DataTable`. One of the columns in this `DataTable` is of some “numeric type” (‘int`or`Double`) and it ONLY contains values of zeros (0s) and ones (1s). Is what you want, is to “change” the values in that column to “As” and “Ps” such that all zeros (0s) become “As” and ones (1s) become “Ps.” I hope I have this correct.

This appears straight forward, and I assume there are numerous ways to do this, however, I am confident you can NOT simply “change” a columns data “type” in an existing `DataTable`. Therefore, it seems obvious that your code is going to have to “ADD” this column to the existing `DataTable`. Something like…

```
originalDataTable.Columns.Add("A/P", typeof(string));
```

Then “after” the column as been added, loop through all the rows in the `DataTable` and set the values for the new “A/P” column. I am aware that this creates an extra column, however, it would be a simple task to remove or simply not display the column of 0s and 1s. Given this, a method `Add_A_P_TextColumn(DataTable dt, string colName)` … that takes a `DataTable` we want to add the column to and a `string` name to identify the column that contains the 0s, and 1s… may come in handy and look something like…

```
private void Add_A_P_TextColumn(DataTable dt, string colName) {
  dt.Columns.Add("A/P", typeof(string));
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
    row["A/P"] = (int)row[colName] == 0 ? "A" : "P";
  }
}
```

This should add the column as described and it is your choice to either remove the column of 0s and 1s or not. To demonstrate a complete and reproducible example, the complete code below demonstrates using the above method. To start, drop a `DataGridView` and a `Button` onto a form like below.

[image]

When the form loads, the code gets a column of random 0s and 1s for test data. This would be the original data your code gets from the data base. This is what the picture shows. When the user clicks the button, the `Add_A_P_TextColumn` method is called to add the "A/P" column.

```
DataTable OriginalTable;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  OriginalTable = GetOriginalTable();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = OriginalTable;
}

private DataTable GetOriginalTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("0/1", typeof(int));
  Random rand = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add(rand.Next(2));
  }
  return dt;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Add_A_P_TextColumn(OriginalTable, "0/1");
}
```

I hope this clears some things up.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate over Cells as well:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        int d = Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value);
        if (d == 0)
           cell.Value = "A";
        else
           cell.Value = "P";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but even i update the single value it gives same error